# OSGi, Jetty - exposing the server to the outside

Tags: java, debian, jetty, osgi

As a topic. I have the task to issue an OSGi, Jetty server on the outside. I have a host (Debian). I have read that this type of server best place with the help of Virgo.

Virgo Jetty server installed on Debian.
Just I do not know where I got there, throw your plug-in project to make it work.

Any suggestions? For all the answers, very thanks.

Comment: This question is bit too unspecific. What have you tried, what erorrs did you see? Did you do any virgo tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the virgo user guide. Especially [starting / stopping chapter](https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.5.0.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-user-guide.html#starting-stopping) and [deploying artifacts](https://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.5.0.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/htmlsingle/virgo-user-guide.html#deployment-deploying).

Alternatively you might want to take a look at Apache Karaf. It is similar to virgo but works mainly using maven repostories. So you just build your OSGi application with maven and deploy it into karaf directly from maven. See [karaf user guide](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/index.html) and [karaf tutorials](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials).

Comment: Thank you very much, in the morning I see and let you know if helped :)